# Can I downgrade from SharePoint 2019 to SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, 2019

Is it possible to use backup data from the 2019 version of SharePoint and restore it to the 2016 version?

Or is there any other way to downgrade from 2019 to the 2016 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. The only supported way would be to use a migration tool such as Sharegate.

Comment: So, this Sharegate is support to migrate data form 2019 to 2016 ver?
Thanks for the information. I`m gonna check it.

Comment: This answer seems contradictory. Is it possible or is it not possible? I'd suggest an edit, but don't want to put words in your mouth.

Comment: I think Sharegate doesn't support this kind of downgrade on database side

Comment: It isn't possible with out of the box tooling. It is possible with 3rd party migration tools.

Answer (score 2):

Restore from a newer version to an older version is called **Backward compatibility** that not supported in SharePoint as well as SQL Server.

Only **Forward Compatibility** is supported. otherwise, you will need to use a 3rd party migration tool to can restore to an earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported by Microsoft. We are not able to downgrade a SharePoint Farm through a supported approach.

Comment: If you are affiliated with Microsoft please mention that explicitly in your post; anyone can add "_MSFT" to their username and you can and probably will change your username at some point in the future, at which point this answer will be confusing re: "we".